# Interface, delegate, other? (C#, Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I have:

```
public void New_Click()
{           
    MenuManager.GoToMenu(MenuName.NewDescr);
    StartCoroutine(WaitForClose());          
}

IEnumerator WaitForClose()
{
   yield return new WaitWhile(MenuManager.MenuOpen);
   listMonitor.AddToGrid(Descriptor.List.Last());
   yield return null;
}
```

What I want:

```
public void New_Click()
{
    MenuManager.GoToMenu(MenuName.NewDescr);
    WaitForClose(listMonitor.AddToGrid(Descriptor.List.Last()));
}
```

Basically, I'd like to implement a wrapper around a method call, but not have to specify StartCoroutine() nor write out the WaitForClose() method every time the method is used. I have little experience with delegates and Interfaces - are those the answer? If so, how?

Comment: Please tell us more specifically what you want and also the context, question is kind of abstract and hard to understand what exactly do you want to implement

Comment: Two thoughts come to mind (1) Can you make `New_Click` an async method? (2) Do your menus publish a "MenuClosed" event?

Comment: I think there is a way in unity to alleviate the `async/await` feature of c# (like `await MenuBtnClicked()`)

Comment: @JohnWu Alas, I am only barely getting going with Unity's Coroutines and its internal Event system, and have not fully grasped async methods and events in C#. That is the essence of what is going on, though. MenuManager.MenuOpen is simply a bool toggle; while true, the IEnumerator method remains paused and does not advance to the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generalize the `WaitForClose()` method you've shown by allowing an `Action` delegate to be passed. E.g.:

```cs
public void New_Click()
{           
    MenuManager.GoToMenu(MenuName.NewDescr);
    StartCoroutine(WaitForClose(() => listMonitor.AddToGrid(Descriptor.List.Last())));          
}

IEnumerator WaitForClose(Action action)
{
   yield return new WaitWhile(MenuManager.MenuOpen);
   action();
   yield return null;
}
```

Extending the above, you can then simplify the invocation a bit so it's closer to your "what I want" example:

```cs
public void New_Click()
{           
    MenuManager.GoToMenu(MenuName.NewDescr);
    WaitForClose(() => listMonitor.AddToGrid(Descriptor.List.Last()));          
}

void WaitForClose(Action action)
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitForCloseCoroutine(action));
}

IEnumerator WaitForCloseCoroutine(Action action)
{
   yield return new WaitWhile(MenuManager.MenuOpen);
   action();
   yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! This is definitely what I was thinking of when I brought up delegates. Doing this allows for "WaitForClose()" to be more versatile and generic.
Two questions: 1) Can the call be shortened to WaitForClose(listMonitor.Method()); or is using the lambda expression necessary? 
2) Now that WaitForClose() is generic, what's the optimal way to offload it so that multiple classes can use it? My go to would be a static public class (ex. Utils.WaitForClose() ), or Inheritance, but perhaps there is a better way? That's where I was wondering if Interfaces were the solution.

Comment: _"Can the call be shortened"_ -- that will depend on the nature of the action. If the `Descriptor.List.Last()` aspect is invariant (i.e. always used), then you could change the delegate type to match the `AddToGrid()` method signature, and then the call site could look like `WaitForClose(listMonitor.AddToGrid)`, with the `WaitForCloseCoroutine()` method calling the `Descriptor.List.Last()` part and passing that to the delegate. But if you need a completely general-purpose wrapper, then no...you'll always need to provide a full lambda that does whatever you need.

Comment: _"what's the optimal way to offload it"_ -- that's entirely up to you. Stuff like this does generally work well in a static class somewhere. It probably doesn't belong in the object hierarchy itself, but it hard to say for sure without more details. There's even a small possibility it could be an extension method, depending on usage (e.g. an extension for whatever the `Descriptor` part of the call return). Impossible to say for sure without more details; that's really a whole other question you should post if you're having difficulty with it.

Answer (score 0):

Peter had EXACTLY where I was going to go.  But since you are completely new to the concept and will probably read more about it, I will start you with this.

The keyword "Action", instead of things like int, string, someClass, etc, you are telling this method that you want a procedure/method to be called when the specific point-in-time comes as Peter demonstrates by calling the lower-case "action()".

The other cool thing you can do is even allow actions that require some sort of additional parameters.  Maybe you want to conditionally have some time delay to allow, values to compute, or whatever else.  You can specify what data type parameters you want to pass in as well.  The only difference is the signature such as

```
public void SomeFunction( Action<int> doSomething )
{
    // suppose some randomized value that you want the function to handle
    var someRand = SomeIntValueFromSomeRandomFunction();
    // notice the Action signature is saying it should be a function that 
    // will expect and integer data type to be passed to it when actually called.
    // above I get some random number, then call that Action method with it.
    doSomething( someRand );
}
```

Similarly you can do things with FUNCTIONS that RETURN values.  The only difference is the last parameter is the expected data type being returned AFTER the function is called.

[Using ACTIONS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-5.0)
[Using FUNCTIONS as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0)